# Access VBA SQL fails to execute

Tags: vba

Using the following code that generates

> Error:(2342) A Run SQL action requires an action consisting of an SQL
>   statement

Here is the code:

```
Dim Lping As Variant
Lping = "SELECT dbo_Log_Table.LogID"
Lping = Lping + " FROM dbo_Log_Table"
Lping = Lping + " WHERE (((dbo_Log_Table.LogID)=1))"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL Lping
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

The SQL is copied from the QBE grid and executes from there.  I have other such code, but can't see the problem with this.

Thanks in advance

JPL

Comment: What is the value of Lping when running RunSQL() ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `DoCmd.RunSQL` runs action statements: `Insert`, `Update`, `Delete`. A select statement doesn't *do* anything. You have no way of obtaining the results of this query and using them and thus `RunSQL` doesn't even let you waste your time doing it.

If you want to use the results of this query you'll need to create a `QueryDef`, a query object and use that, or explicitly generate a recordset. Either way the Query needs to get into a recordset to be used.